# How to stop multiple mails at one time?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

I am trying to send email with intent, but it is going with multiple mail id's because I am using multiple email id's in my android device. So I want to send the email with only one email id, at one time.
For example:- I am using two mail id's xxx@gmail.com and yyy@gmail.com.
 So my code is sending mail by default with both of mail id's.

> ```
>    protected void sendEmail() {
>     String[] TO = {"zzz@gmail.com"};
>     Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
>       emailIntent.setType("text/plain");    
>       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
>       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
>       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here"); 
>       try {
>              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
>              finish();
>                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
>              finish();
>              Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
>           } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
>              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
>              "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>           }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it was my big mistake. I was using following code two times. That's why it was sending email randomly two times.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
```